# I have text in B1:B15, if text in B17 = anything from B1:B15 return in C17 true otherwise false

Tags: excel-2010

I'm trying to write a string that can cover off all text in B1:B15 but get stuck when comes to adding beyond the first part which I can get to work.
I have this so far =IF((B17=B1),"North")
I then want to continue so covers off B1:B8 as North and B9:B15 as South based on selection made

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQyeI.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question title says you want to see 'True' or 'False' in C17 depending on whether or not the value in B17 is in the list B1:B15. Try this in C17:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B17,B1:B15,1,FALSE)))
```

If instead of just getting true/false you want to return the value in column C depending on which value was matched in column B then you would use:

```
=VLOOKUP(B17,B1:C15,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it, the second is what I am after. Yes subject was not edited before posting, my bad. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're asking because your example image has nothing in B17.I assume you're writing your equation in C1?

If I'm following what you're asking, what you actually probably want to do is, in C1:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B17,$B$1:$C$15,2,0),"Not found")
```

Then fill that equation down as far as you need to go in column C. The iferror means if the vlookup fails to find something, it'll display that message, which you can make whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I will follow your logic

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1:B16,A17)>0,"True","false")
```

***"If the number of coincidences of A17 in the range B1:B16 is bigger than 1 then 'True', else 'false'"***